# Label x axis in degrees

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a graph that plots flux density against longitude points:

[image]

but I need the x-axis to read from 24.3 -> 0 in the center -> 335.7

I've used matplotlib.ticker to set the ticks every 30 pixels, equal to every 1 degree.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

hdulist = fits.open('w1_subtracted_2_deg.fits')
nodisk_data, nodisk_header = hdulist[0].data, hdulist[0].header

x = range(nodisk_data.shape[1])
y = np.sum(nodisk_data, axis = 0)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(300))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(30))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('Longitudinal sum of flux density per steradian')
plt.xlabel(r'Galactic longitude, $\ell$')
plt.ylabel(r'Integrated flux density per steradian, $MJ.sr^{-1}$')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('add_cols.png')  

hdulist.close()
```

Is there a simple command that I can use for this, maybe in the `axes` class, or do I need to hard-code a list of the x-axis points? Or maybe set the center pixel as the reference pixel and have the plot labelled 24.3 degrees in either direction around the circle?

Comment: I would do this by first altering the _values_ along the x-axis to the correct degrees, and then plotting the degree values and letting the ticks be automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the x-axis labels like this:

```
xticks = [0, 183, 365, 547, 729, 912, 1095, 1277, 1459]
long_marks = [24, 18, 12, 6, 0, 354, 348, 342, 335]
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(long_marks)
```